# How to validate password using express-validator npm

Tags: regex, node.js, validation, express

I am writing rest API using node , express web module. For validation I am using **express-validator** npm. I want to apply some validation rules on password field.

How can I achieve it using express-validator?

What validation rules I want to apply for password as:

1. min 8 char long.
2. At least one uppercase.
3. At least one lower case.
4. At least one special character.

I read in [this](https://aomm1ez.blogspot.in/2013/03/nodejs-validator.html) link that there is a function available called **regex()** . So I tried it but not working at all.

My approach:

```
req.check("password", "Password should be combination of one uppercase , one lower case, one special char, one digit and min 8 , max 20 char long").regex("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/", "i");
```

**Error**

[image]

In **[express-js](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)**  they have listed all the methods but did not find method / trick which solve my problem.

Comment: As per my research I found that it is possible using express-validator's custom validation function. But do I need to define 4 functions to check it or is there any regex pattern function is available ??

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort on your part. You're asking people to do your work for you. You subsequently found the `customValidators` option, but it's still unclear what you tried yourself, and where you got stuck. Looking at the documentation, checking against a regex seems trivial to me.

Comment: https://github.com/mlabieniec/complexity This has a nice solution to build the RegEx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The link you're referring to is almost 3 years old. Since then, the API of `validator` changed.

To check against a regular expression, use `.matches()`:

```
req.check("password", "...").matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/, "i");
```

Comment: I have used 'matches()' in first attempt but I made a silly mistake. I put pattern in quotes. like 

' req.check("password", "...").matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/, "i"); ' .

Comment: now it is working. perfectly. :). Still I think my question does not fall in down vote bucket. In future definitely it will help others.

Comment: @SunilSharma not anymore, no. I didn't downvote but I'll upvote to get it back to 0.

Comment: @robertklep can you please explain the regex.

Comment: @dewnor check out [this page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password), which does a pretty good job explaining how something similar works :)

Answer (score 11):

I believe the accepted answer is outdated. [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) are not the best ways to validate passwords in 2017, as the obscurity of regular expressions makes the app unmaintainable and prone to bugs.

[password-validator](https://github.com/tarunbatra/password-validator) makes it easy to define password rules and maintain them. Here's a sample:

```
var passwordValidator = require('password-validator');

var schema = new passwordValidator();

schema
  .is().min(8)
  .is().max(100)
  .has().uppercase()
  .has().lowercase();

console.log(schema.validate(req.body.password)); // prints a boolean
```

PS: I'm the author of the [password-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-validator).

Answer (score 7):

Theres a new solution for this. From the documentation:

Check if a password is strong or not. Allows for custom requirements or scoring rules. If returnScore is true, then the function returns an integer score for the password rather than a boolean.
Default options:

```js
body('password').isStrongPassword({
  minLength: 8,
  minLowercase: 1,
  minUppercase: 1,
  minNumbers: 1,
  minSymbols: 1,
  returnScore: false,
  pointsPerUnique: 1,
  pointsPerRepeat: 0.5,
  pointsForContainingLower: 10,
  pointsForContainingUpper: 10,
  pointsForContainingNumber: 10,
  pointsForContainingSymbol: 10,
})
```

Comment: its work!. Thank you so much. I want to understand more about it, but I can't find the docs. Do you have url to it?

Comment: Here you go: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Comment: thank for replying, but I know that docs, what i mean is isStrongPassword function's doc. Do you have it?

Comment: Im sorry. I don't know any other docs. You can check the source code and take a look at the tests if there are any. But I think it should be pretty self-explanatory with the params I included

Comment: I found it again: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators

Answer (score 5):

Using the built in validators of express-validator I was able to use built in validators without a regex to check the password.

```
const validateStrongPassword = body("password")
  .isString()
  .isLength({ min: 8 })
  .not()
  .isLowercase()
  .not()
  .isUppercase()
  .not()
  .isNumeric()
  .not()
  .isAlpha();
```

This verifies that there is at least one non letter character, one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, a minimum length and that there are letters in the password.

Answer (score 4):

Chosen answer is incomplete as it's missing validation for special characters. Correct answer should be:

`req.checkBody("password", "Password must include one lowercase character, one uppercase character, a number, and a special character.").matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/, "i");`

Only real difference is that I added the `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` expression which ensures a user is using a character that's not a number or letter.

Answer (score 2):

```
check(
      "password1",
      "Please enter a password at least 8 character and contain At least one uppercase.At least one lower case.At least one special character. ",
    )
.isLength({ min: 8 })
.matches(
          /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d@$.!%*#?&]/,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an array for validation and therefore the req object is not available, you can also do the following:

```
body('field_name').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/, "i").withMessage('Password should be combination of one uppercase , one lower case, one special char, one digit and min 8 , max 20 char long'),
```

Answer (score -2):

matches method work but I think it's not a stable for this use case, I think you should use the custom() method my code's :

this method work with tow parameters first is the value of your fieldset that in check method for example check('name field or password field') and the second value is an object that includes req object and you can use them and return a true or false if your returned value is true it's ok but if you return false its problem and validation is failed.

I write code in different shapes.

```
router.post('/adduser', [check('name').isLength({
    min: 2,
    max: 25
}).withMessage('min character 2 nad max character 25').custom((value, {req}) => {
    return !req.body.name.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)
}).withMessage('please write a correct name'),
    check('family').isLength({
        min: 2,
        max: 25
    }).withMessage('min character 2 nad max character 25').custom((value, {req}) => {
        return !req.body.name.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)
    }).withMessage('please write a correct family'),
    check('number').custom((value, {req}) => {
    return !req.body.name.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)
})], (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(validationResult(req).errors)
})
```