# Best practice for validating passwords with express validator's isStrongPassword()

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, passwords, express-validator

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225980/13516162) from @Huhngut provides a succinct way to test the strength of passwords using the `express-validator` method `isStrongPassword()`.  For example:

```js
body('password').isStrongPassword({
  minLength: 12,
  minLowercase: 1,
  minUppercase: 1,
  minNumbers: 1,
  minSymbols: 1,
})
```

However this code above allows me to enter anything into the password field which makes me concerned that could pose a security risk.  I would like to ask:

1. Which non-alphanumeric characters should be allowed?
2. Is there a preferred `express-validator` method for implementing allowable characters e.g.
   `.matches()`/`.whitelist()`etc.
3. Is there a recommended maximum length for passwords, and how should that be implemented since `.isStrongPassword()` doesn't have a maximum length option?

More generally I am trying to find the best practice for implementing logic within `express-validator` and `node.js` that minimizes the risk to my server while enforcing strong passwords.

Comment: This may be a controversial topic, but classic industry password strength standards foster insecure passwords. I'm not sure what Express uses specifically these days, but this should give a proper answer https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3924.

Comment: This information is best provided from an authoritative source, such as the National Institute of Standards and Technology. As of today, this is current recommendation for [Digital Identity Guidelines: Authentication and Lifecycle Management](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-63b). In the future, please visit the [publication webpage](https://www.nist.gov/publications/digital-identity-guidelines-authentication-and-lifecycle-management) for the latest revision.